# Handling dynamic form

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to handle dynamic spring form. The point is, that before runtime i dont know exactly how many inputs form have. I don know name of inputs or any kind of info that can be used with @RequestParam.

Here is my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/surveys/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String survey(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("surveyForm", getQAForm(id));
    return "user/survey";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/submitSurvey", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitSurvey(@ModelAttribute("surveyForm") QAForm qaForm, ModelMap modelMap){
    Set<Answer> answers = qaForm.getAnswers();
    modelMap.addAttribute("answers", answers);
    return "test";
}
```

And jsp's:

```
       <f:form method="post" modelAttribute="surveyForm" action="/submitSurvey">>
        <h2>${surveyForm.survey.title}</h2>
        <h5>${surveyForm.survey.description}</h5>
        <c:forEach items="${surveyForm.answers}" var="answer">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                ${answer.question.text}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <f:input path="${answer.answerText}" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </c:forEach>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
      </f:form>
```

After handling /submitSurvey request its simple redirect to test.jsp without any information from form. If there is any way to handle this another way, i'll be grateful for a point me in right direction.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @AlanHay How to get result from this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you are asking however if it is around binding a collection you will need to make the following changes.

1. Answers will need to be stored in a List and not a Set. i.e. qaForm.getAnswers() must return a List as Spring can only bind to a collection accessible by index.
2. Change the JSP markup to use indexed properties as follows:

.

```
<c:forEach items="${surveyForm.answers}" var="answer" varStatus="status">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                ${answer.question.text}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <f:input path="answer[${status.index}].answerText" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
</c:forEach>
```

To populate an existing survey on submit make the changes below (as per http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

1. Add a hidden field in your form which submits the surveyId.
2. Add a method to your controller as below which will load the specified survey and bind the submitted data to this existing instance.

.

```
@ModelAttribute("surveyForm")
public SurveyForm getSurveyForm(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer surveyId){
    if(id != null){ 
       //load the form required by id   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now i've got another problem, when i'll return my surveyForm, Answer object didn't contains Question, User, only answerText field is available. Is it normal behavior? And how to get this object from my jsp?

Comment: You need to populate an existing survey. Spring will be creating a new one. See update.

Comment: Prob because the form submit url does not include the path variable.

Comment: Everything working fine if delete  @PathVariable int id  from getSurveyForm(), but then i cant access to a choosen survey. It is becouse of missing path variable? If yes, where should i add it?

Comment: Okay, revert your code for GET to how it was before i.e looks up by path variable. Then see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/surveys/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String survey(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model,@RequestParam("description") String desc) {
   // here you can handl the param description
    model.addAttribute("surveyForm", getQAForm(id));
    return "user/survey";
 }
```

But you should have this param in your form in your page jsp like:

```
  <f:form method="post" modelAttribute="surveyForm" action="/submitSurvey">>
<input type="text" name="description" />
 ....
```